# Comentario para cada post id sem multiplicação do mesmo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Primeiro vejam a imagem de minha database (as setas de ligação de uma tabela para outra são os `inner join`'s): http://prntscr.com/6wjl4h

#### Query atual:

```
"SELECT
question.*,
questioncomments.*,
login.*
FROM questioncomments
INNER JOIN question
ON questioncomments.comment_question_ID = question.question_ID
INNER JOIN login
ON question.autor_id = login.user_ID
ORDER BY question.question_ID";
```

#### Parte do meu código PHP:

```
<?php
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<hr>[Row 'titulo'] TITLE: " . $row["titulo"] . "<br><br>QUESTION: " . $row["question"] . "<br><br>COMMENT:  " . $row["comment"] . "<br><br>"; 
}
?>
```

---

### Pergunta:

Como ter os comentários incluidos em cada "question_id" ao invés de multiplicar cada questão com cada resposta?

---

#### Resultado esperado (antes veja o resultado ruim):

> TITULO: Please help me
>
> QUESTION: What is GOOGLE?
>
> COMMENT: is a searcher
>
> COMMENT: is a game

#### Resultado ruim:

> TITULO: Please help me
>
> QUESTION: What is GOOGLE?
>
> COMMENT: is a searcher
>
> ---
>
> TITULO: Please help me
>
> QUESTION: What is GOOGLE?
>
> COMMENT: is a game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// VARIAVEL DE CONTROLE PARA TROCA DE QUESTÃO.
$idControle = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // A QUESTÃO ATUAL É DIFERENTE DA QUESTÃO ANTERIOR? SE FOR IMPRIME CABEÇALHO.
    if($idControle != $row['question_ID']){
        echo "<hr> TITLE: " . $row["titulo"] . "<br><br>QUESTION: " . $row["question"]."    <br>";
    }
    echo "<br>COMMENT:  " . $row["comment"] . "<br>"; 

    // ATUALIZA VARIAVEL DE CONTROLE.
    $idControle = $row['question_ID'];
}
```

Comment: vo tentar isto , não obtive nada ainda por causa dos erros do seu código

Comment: OBRIGADO <3 VOCÊ É UM GÊNIO!!!!!!!11

Comment: Poderia me fazer um resumo traduzido do que este codigo faz ? Ele funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Comment: Eu criei uma variável de controle $idControle que é iniciada com 0. Na primeira iteração do while vamos supor que o question_ID é 1, o IF vai verificar se (0 != 1), se for ele vai imprimir o cabeçalho da questão e logo depois o primeiro comentário, então $idControle recebe 1.
Na próxima iteração ele so vai imprimir o cabeçalho da questão de novo se o question_ID for diferente de 1. 
Ficou um pouco confuso, mas deu pra entender?